# Excel formula to count discrete instances of referenced cells

Tags: excel

I have a column of strings, representing names, where there can be more than one name per cell and each is separated by a semicolon. There is a column next to it that has a single character which represents a category. To illustrate:

[image: Problem]

My desired outcome is shown in the second box. What I need is a formula that, for each name in column B, counts up how many instances of the categories in column C were assigned to it.

I'm having difficulty reconciling the fact that there may be multiple names in each cell in column B. Can anyone think of an easy approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `COUNTIFS` and wildcards:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$5,"*"&$G3&"*",$C$2:$C$5,H$2)
```

[image]